# is there anyway to detect which part of hand is touching the object in interaction engine (Leap Motion & Unity3D)

Tags: unity-game-engine, leap-motion

I am trying to build a application which includes using leap motion interaction engine to move the object in unity 3d. However, i also need to find out which fingers are touching the object when interacting with object in unity. Is there anyway i can do that? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I guess, when you check from the editor it shows hands as L and R, it also does this for fingers from 1 to 5. If you can't get those names directly, add empty gameObjects with colliders on them as child to fingers and hands and use `OnTriggerEnter` to get the names of the fingers or hands you want

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however the interaction engine requires brush hands instead of rigid hand and i couldn't find any fingers in brush hands. Please correct me if i am wrong. Thanks!

Comment: It has been a while since I've worked with leap motion. What I recall is, I've used magnetic pinch to grab objects. Also, i was able to hold objects in my palm like grabbing a handful of water from a river, hitting them with the back of my hand. Do you have the demo scenes for Unity? There should be example scenes like `lots of cubes` was the scene name I guess. Check the hands used in that scene if you did not before. They might give you a lead. And I am not sure if I used interaction engine or not. Sorry for foggy comment.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, the Grasping logic of the Interaction Engine has to check this very thing in order to initiate or release grasps, but it doesn't have a friendly API for accessing this information.

A more convenient way to express this, even though it's not the most efficient way, would be to detect when a hand is intersecting with the interaction object and checking the distance between each fingertip and the object.

All InteractionControllers that are intersecting with a given InteractionBehaviour can be accessed via its `contactingControllers` property; using the `Query` library included in Leap tools for Unity, you can convert a bunch of Interaction Controller references to a bunch of Leap Hands without too much effort, and then perform the check:

```cs
using Leap.Unity;
using Leap.Unity.Interaction;
using Leap.Unity.Query;
using UnityEngine;

public class QueryFingertips : MonoBehaviour {

  public InteractionBehaviour intObj;

  private Collider[] _collidersBuffer = new Collider[16];
  private float _fingertipRadius = 0.01f; // 1 cm

  void FixedUpdate() {
    foreach (var contactingHand in intObj.contactingControllers
                                         .Query()
                                         .Select(controller => controller.intHand)
                                         .Where(intHand => intHand != null)
                                         .Select(intHand => intHand.leapHand)) {

      foreach (var finger in contactingHand.Fingers) {
        var fingertipPosition = finger.TipPosition.ToVector3();

        // If the distance from the fingertip and the object is less
        // than the 'fingertip radius', the fingertip is touching the object.
        if (intObj.GetHoverDistance(fingertipPosition) < _fingertipRadius) {
          Debug.Log("Found collision for fingertip: " + finger.Type);
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```